# How can I know when the last async call in a group is completed?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, task

If I'm running a series of `async Tasks` in C#, is there a reliable way for me to know when the last of the set has completed?

Note: The number of `Tasks` I'm creating is not known ahead of time, so I'll only know when I'm done creating them after an external condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task>)` creates a task that completes when all the tasks in the argument list have completed.

Comment: I'm creating my instances of `Task` very quickly, on the fly.  Is there a way that I can add them as I'm making them and still have that functionality?

Comment: Add them to a collection as you go, and then invoke `WhenAll()` on the collection.  If they have all completed by the time you exit your loop, the output of `WhenAll` will complete immediately.

Comment: Aha!  I had just thought of that just as you posted this. Perfect! ;)

Comment: You might also want to look at the `yield return` construct -- it sounds like that might fit your case.

Comment: I'll look into that.  It might not be necessary as I'll just accumulate all my `Task` instances where I call them and pass them to the method I call once I'm done queueing things up.